# Snowflake SQL group-by behaving differently depending whether columns are referenced by position or alias

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to understand why the group by function is yielding different results in snowflake depending on how I reference the group-by fields. Here are two Queries that I believe should yield the same result, but do NOT:

Query using explicit field alias references:

```
select
    hash('SHA2_256', CONCAT(field1,field2,field3,field4)) as hash
    ,field1
    ,field2
    ,field3
    ,field4
    ,count(*) as count
from <table>
    where 
        <some filters>
    group by hash, field1, field2, field3, field4;
```

Query using positional references to fields:

```
select
    hash('SHA2_256', CONCAT(field1,field2,field3,field4)) as hash
    ,field1
    ,field2
    ,field3
    ,field4
    ,count(*) as count
from <table>
    where 
        <same filters as above>
    group by 1,2,3,4,5;
```

The first query yields significantly more records, suggesting maybe it isn't applying a grouping field that is being applied in the second query, but based on the [snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/group-by) I really believe they should be the same. How are these two different?

Comment: Any chance to get sample data or query profiles?

Comment: Second does the table `<table>` have its own `hash` column? If yes, then hash at GROUP BY is `<table>.hash` and not the computed one

Comment: I am not familiar with snowflake, but I note the docs do not say you can use an alias in the group by.  my guess is the name 'hash' is being resolved to the hash function instead of the alias

Comment: @LukaszSzozda You are correct. "hash" was already a column name in the source table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue is that the aliased expression `hash` does not overshadow existing columns so:

```
select
     hash('SHA2_256', CONCAT(field1,field2,field3,field4)) as hash
    ,field1
    ,field2
    ,field3
    ,field4
    ,count(*) as count
from <table>
where <some filters>
group by hash, field1, field2, field3, field4;
```

is

```
select
     hash('SHA2_256', CONCAT(field1,field2,field3,field4)) as hash
    ,field1
    ,field2
    ,field3
    ,field4
    ,count(*) as count
from <table>
where <some filters>
group by <table>.hash, field1, field2, field3, field4;
```

which  is different than:

```
select
     hash('SHA2_256', CONCAT(field1,field2,field3,field4)) as hash
    ,field1
    ,field2
    ,field3
    ,field4
    ,count(*) as count
from <table>
where <same filters as above>
group by 1,2,3,4,5;
```

Comment: Note: [Snowflake Ideas](https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas) search for: "Lateral column aliasing - new keyword to distinguish between original column vs expression named same as column"